# Terminating QWidget doesn't work

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I used `self.close` to close the widget that is running. Whole code is as follows:

```
class timeTracker(QWidget):
        '''time tracker main application v_0.8'''
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(timeTracker, self).__init__(parent)
        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.grid)

        while not self.connectivity():
            print(self.connectivity())
            ret = QMessageBox.warning(self, "Not connected to network. Please check the connection", "", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.Yes)
            if ret == QMessageBox.No:
                self.close()
                qApp.quit()
                break
            qApp.quit()
        # self.time_widget = timeline.timeWidget()
        # self.grid.addWidget(self.time_widget, 0, 0)


    def connectivity(self):
        try:
            urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.google.com", timeout=1)
            return True
        except urllib.error.URLError as error:
            return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_widget = timeTracker()
    main_widget.show()
    main_widget.move(10, 10)
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

What I expect from this code is, as long as the connectivity function is returning True, user will be repeatedly asked to do the certain action if they click yes. If they click no, I would like to terminate the whole widget. But when I click no, then it just goes through the lines after the self.close. What can I do to actually terminate the program?

Comment: what is `check_function()`?

Comment: Blocking loops are not user friendly for GUI design, there are other options like using QTimers. But with the code you provide it is impossible to help you.

Comment: @eyllanesc `check_function()` actually checks the network connection, and clicking yes will check the network, and if connected, emit `False` and progress to the next codes. But clicking no, therefore executing self.close() is not closing the application running.

Comment: If you do that task, I recommend creating a QThread that performs this task, and emit some signal by doing the task of displaying the warning in the main thread. If you show that function I could put the appropriate code.

Comment: @eyllanesc I've uploaded my whole codes, and I'll take a look at the QThread. Thanks in advance!

Comment: One query: what is timeWidget? Is it necessary to place it?

Comment: @eyllanesc that's the main point of the application, and if I place it without network connection check, the data may be corrupted... So I wanted to make sure that I have network connection before I put the timeWidget in the  main widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close an application forcefully as in this case we can use [`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit)

```
if ret == QMessageBox.No:
    sys.exit(0)
```